# How to refresh page with window.location.reload() using jestjs to mock real behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, browser-history

I can't force my page to refresh when testing my component.

I have a functional component in React that when a button is pressed refreshes the page.
Here is the component that I tried to simplify as much as possible :

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Component: React.FC<{ initialData?: string | undefined }> = ({ initialData = undefined }) => {
    const [someInternalData, setSomeInternalData] = useState(initialData);
    const [someBoolean, setSomeBoolean] = useState(false);

    const location:any = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => 
        {
            if(location.state == null){
                console.log("first implementation");
            } else {
                const someDataFromLocation:string|undefined = location.state.someData;
                if(someDataFromLocation) {
                    setInternalData(someDataFromLocation);
                    setSomeBoolean(true);
                }
            }
        }
        ,
        [setSomeInternalData]
    );

    function refreshPage() {
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title);
        window.location.reload();
    }

    return(
        <div>
           <div>
              <button type="button" data-testid="refresh-button" onClick={refreshPage}>Refresh</button>
           </div>
           ...//Need of the variable someBoolean for decide of what to display after
        </div>
    );
}

export default Component;
```

To test this component I made the following test in which I want to call the window.location.reload() method at some point:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

import Component from './Component';

//Other mock function for axios and child component but I don't need it for the problematic part of my test, I don't think it's the problem.
jest.mock('axios');
const mockChildComponent = jest.fn();

describe('Component', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  beforeEach(()=>{
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  const reload = window.location.reload;

  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      value: { reload: jest.fn() }
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    window.location.reload = reload;
  });

  test('it can be clicked', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(window.location, 'reload');

    render(<Router>
            <Sessions />
          </Router>,);

    //I then test the different functionality of my component which works very well until I need to call window.location.reload in my component

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(/refresh-button/i));

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); //OK but it's normal that it works because I mocked it

      //Expect some element to be visible on the page after I refresh but fail because window.location.state didn't work and I still have my old page
      expect(screen.queryByTestId(/some-test-id/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

      //Expect some other element to not be visible on the page after I refresh but fail because window.location.state didn't work and I still have my old page
      expect(screen.queryByTestId(/some-other-test-id/i)).toBeNull();
    });
  });
});
```

As I tried to explain in the comments, after testing the different functionalities of my component which works well, I then test the refresh button.

Once I get to the part of the test that will use `window.location.reload()`, the test can continue but the page doesn't reload, the data remains the same as at the beginning of the test and is not reset to 0.

Do you know how to force a page refresh in the mocked method of window.location.reload()?

Thank you in advance if you take the time to help me